# Android Dex BufferOverflowException in MapApp

Tags: java, android, eclipse, indoor-positioning-system

This is the error I faced while running the application. Help please. Thank you.

```
[2013-12-06 15:08:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-12-06 15:08:34 - MapApp_Final] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

Error which I got from stack trace:

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putShort(Unknown Source)
at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeShort(Dex.java:818)
at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeTypeList(Dex.java:870)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$3.write(DexMerger.java:437)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$3.write(DexMerger.java:423)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeUnsorted(DexMerger.java:317)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeTypeLists(DexMerger.java:423)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:163)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:813)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1116)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: **Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.**, did you do it?

Comment: Try to clear cache of your map application in your device settings>application.

Comment: I had the same issue and I just restarted eclipse and clean my project and build again. Try this may be it will work for you too. I think this isn't an error with map app. It has something to do with the sdk tools latest version. Google it a bit you will find about this error.

Comment: Have you added the support libraries ?